# jQuery get attribute of children element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an issue regarding getting the attributes of the children elements.

```
$ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
    //var cat =  $(".bear_image").children("img").attr("alt");
    var abs = $("li");
    $(abs).on("click", ".first", function(){
        var cat = $(this).children(".bear_image img");
        console.log(cat.attr("alt"));
    });
});
```

It shows undefined.

Here is my php code:

```
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="bear-id" value=<?php echo $bears['id']; ?>>
        <div class="bear_image"><img src="<?php echo $bears['nuotrauka']['url'];?>" alt=<?php echo $bears['id']; ?>></div>
        <div class="icons">
            <div class="first" id="1"><?php echo '<img src="' . content_url( '/themes/NutMEDIA/images/bow.png', __FILE__ ) . '" > '; ?></div>
            <div class="second" id="2" ><?php echo '<img src="' . content_url( '/themes/NutMEDIA/images/tie.png', __FILE__ ) . '" > '; ?></div>
            <div class="third" id="3"><?php echo '<img src="' . content_url( '/themes/NutMEDIA/images/heart.png', __FILE__ ) . '" > '; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <p class="bear_description"><?php echo $bears['aprasymas'];?></p>
    </li>
```

**I need to output the alt of .bear_image img**

Comment: `div.first` has no children with class `.bear_image`

Comment: try `console.log(cat);` first to see if your selector is even getting any elements

Comment: The thing is that divs are not related they are separate when I click I have to make actions in other div.

Comment: replace `var cat = ...` with `var cat = $(this).parents('li').find('> .bear_image img');`

Comment: THANKS RAFAEL U ARE HERO :)))))

Comment: ps: u should bind the click event to `ul` tag instead of EACH li u have.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this...

On click, traverse to the parent `li` then find the `.bear_image`

```
$(abs).on("click", ".first", function(){
   var cat = $(this).parents('li').find('.bear_image').attr('alt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(this)` changes scope within the `$.on()` function:

Try:

```
$ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
    //var cat =  $(".bear_image").children("img").attr("alt");
    var abs = $("li");
    abs.on("click", ".first", function(){
        var cat = $(this).closest('li').children(".bear_image img");
        console.log(cat);
    });
});
```

Comment: abs is probably a list of LIs, so if you use `abs.children`, you'll not know which `li .bear_image img` you'll ends with!

Answer (score 0):

The following expression in your code means you are delegating the click handler on class `'.first'` inside the `'li'` container.

```
var abs = $("li");
$(abs).on("click", ".first", function(){
```

Class `first` doesn't have `bear_image` has a child class.

You need to hop to the element with class `bear-image` using the `closest` function and then find the `img` element.

```
var abs = $("li");
    $(abs).on("click", ".first", function(){
            var cat = $(this).closest('.bear_image').find("img"); 
            console.log(cat.attr("alt"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` in the onclick closure function is the `.first` div. This div does not contain any element with a class `.bear_image`.

If you remove the `.bear_image` from the selector it should find the `img` in the `.first` div.

```
$ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
    //var cat =  $(".bear_image").children("img").attr("alt");
    var abs = $("li");
    $(abs).on("click", ".first", function(){
        var cat = $(this).children("img");
        console.log(cat.attr("alt"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.bear_img` is not a child of `.first`, so you have to do a little traversing:

```
var abs = $("li");
$(abs).on("click", ".first", function () {
    var cat = $(this).closest(abs).find(".bear_image img");
    console.log(cat.attr("alt"));
});
```

Here I find the closest list element ancestor, then find the `.bear_image` child of the ancestor.

This [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cd144eqr/) (with PHP code removed) shows how this works.